# Python 3.2 64 Bit Numpy install - LaPack error

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x

I have python's latest 3.2.3 64bit installed on my Windows 7 laptop. I have been trying to use pip to install the packages.

However I am receiving a Lapack error.

> C:\Users\renshaw
>   family\build\numpy\build\py3k\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:13 54:
>   UserWarning:
>
> ```
> Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
>
> Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
>
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
>
> the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
> ```
>
> warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.**doc**)
>
> error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 Storing complete log in
>   C:\Users\renshaw family\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log

I have gone to the [numpy downloads site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.2/) to install via an exe however the site doesn'y have 64bit builds for 3.2 yet. Python(x,y) is only at 2.7 still.

I have found [unofficial builds](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and downloaded numpy-MKL-1.6.2.win-amd64-py3.2.‌exe is this currently the only solution to install unofficial builds?

Answer (score 5):

There is no official way to have numpy 64 bits installed on Windows. This is due to compilation issues on this plateform. However there is unofficial releases using Intel MKL as a replacement to Lapack. Another option is to use a 32 bits Python install instead. But you will be hit by the 2 Gb memory limit.

References :

http://www.scipy.org/Download/#head-f64942d62faddeb27278a2c735e81ef2a7349db0

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/